# How I can write only one django orm query?

Tags: django, orm

The goal is to filter Fitness objects by specified SportType objects, i.e. all Fitness objects which contains at least one specified SportType object as foreignkey.

Here is my models and example:

```py
class Fitness(models.Model):
  name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)

class SportType(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class FitnessSportType(models.Model):
  fitness = models.ForeignKey(Fitness, related_name='sport_type_set')
  sport_type = models.ForeignKey(SportType, related_name='fitness_set')

f1 = Fitness.objects.create(name='foo')
f2 = Fitness.objects.create(name='bar')
f3 = Fitness.objects.create(name='goo')
s1 = SportType.objects.create(name='a')
s2 = SportType.objects.create(name='b')
s3 = SportType.objects.create(name='c')
FitnessSportType.objects.create(fitness=f1, sport_type=s1)
FitnessSportType.objects.create(fitness=f1, sport_type=s2)
FitnessSportType.objects.create(fitness=f2, sport_type=s1)
FitnessSportType.objects.create(fitness=f2, sport_type=s3)
FitnessSportType.objects.create(fitness=f3, sport_type=s2)
SOME_MAGIC_FUNCTION([s1, s3]) = [f1, f2]
```

P.S: sorry for bad English :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use double underscores to traverse relationships and `__in` to test for multiple `SportType`s.

`results = Fitness.objects.filter(sport_type_set__sport_type__in=[s1, s2])`

Answer (score 2):

You can improve this query by explicitly declaring FitnessSportType as the through table in the many-to-many relationship between Fitness and SportType:

```
class Fitness(models.Model):
    ...
    sport_types = models.ManyToManyField('SportType', through='Fitness')
```

Now you can do:

```
Fitness.objects.filter(sport_types__in=[s1, s2])
```

If you don't have any other fields on FitnessSportType, there's no reason to declare it explicitly at all; remove it, and the `through` attribute on the M2M, and the query will work exactly the same.

Comment: I know that there is ManyToManyField, but I have other fields in FitnessSportType. Skipped for simplification.

Comment: You can still use the m2m with through, as I describe.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
FitnessSportType.objects.filter(sport_type='a').values('fitness__name')
```

You will get all fittness name which `sport_type` equal to `a`